# How do I get a PHP array to an angular variable?

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs

I'm coding a website that uses PHP to get information about a match from the database into an array. However, I want to display this information using angular. How could I get the array from the PHP to the angular?

Comment: Hey Alex, Welcome to SO. You'll get better responses if you show code and explain what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the PHP output the information as a JSON object on a different page.

**http://example.com/matchdata.php**

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($match);
?>
```

Then use angular to fetch the data

**http://example.com/display.html**

```
<script>
    // MatchCtrl
    $http.get('http://example.com/matchdata.php').then(function(response){
         $scope.matchData = response;
    })
</script>

<html>
    <div ng-controller="MatchCtrl">
        {{matchData}}
    </div>
<html>
```